# UIAutomator Viewer can't detect the deviced connected from STF(Smartphone Test Farm)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

A mobile device was connected remotely from STF server by issuing following command:

```
C:\Users\tester>adb connect 192.168.0.10:11173
connected to 192.168.0.1:11173
```

then I issued `adb devices` , the remote device appeared in device list:

```
C:\Users\tester>adb devices 
192.168.0.10:11173   device
```

When tried to dump the tree view using UI Automator Viewer in Android Studio, I encountered below problem . It showed the error obtaining device screenshot because no Android deviced by adb.

[image]

Also I attempted to debug my app in Android Studio, this time the device was detected successfully.

So the problem seems to due to that UIAutomator Viewer can't recognize the device name like "IP:PORT". Anyone can provide a solution or a workaround for the problem? Thanks.

BTW, my test environment is:

```
  OS: Windows 7
  AS: 2.3
 ADB: 1.0.39
```

Answer (score 0):

It only support connect device with the usb model, in the source code of Uiautomatorviewer, all actions are done by adb shell command, such as,

```
    procRunner = getAdbRunner(serial, "shell", "/system/bin/uiautomator", "dump", "/sdcard/uidump.xml");
```

where,

```
private ProcRunner getAdbRunner(String serial, String... command) {
        List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmd.add("adb");
        if (serial != null) {
            cmd.add("-s");
            cmd.add(serial);
        }
        for (String s : command) {
            cmd.add(s);
        }
        return new ProcRunner(cmd);
    }
```

so, as you can see, it used the traditional way to connect adb server, if you want to connect with wifi, you need change the code of getAdbRunner().

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) allows connection to devices using IP.

If you want to dump the full tree, run

```
dump -a 192.168.0.10:11173
```